# ASP.NET Webform how to use Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost Prop Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ninject, ninject.web

I have bind all my services in App_Start Ninject.Web.Common and try in my aspx pages [Inject] property injection.

How can I use property injection ? My exception in my webform project.All my injected props are coming null.

Exception Stacktrace :

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2147467261 Message=Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.
>    Source=VDershane.Base StackTrace: konum: VDershane.Base.WebForms.DRecoveryPageLite.LoadLang() c:\Users\Alican Kablan\Documents\Yeni klasör\WebForms\DRecoveryPageLite.cs içinde: satır 158 konum: VDershane.Base.WebForms.DRecoveryPageLite.OnLoad(EventArgs e) c:\Users\Alican Kablan\Documents\Yeni klasör\WebForms\DRecoveryPageLite.cs içinde: satır 191 konum: System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() konum: System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) InnerException:

**My webform project ref**:

Framework 4.5

Ninject 3.3.3

Ninject.Web.Common 3.3.1

Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.3.1

---

In my **Mvc** Projects(I am working like this) :

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }



public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
    }

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        AddBinding();
    }

    private void AddBinding()
    {
        _kernel.Bind<IBlogServices>().To<BlogServices>();
        _kernel.Bind<ILanguageServices>().To<LanguageServices>();
        _kernel.Bind<IFrUserServices>().To<FrUserServices>();
        _kernel.Bind<IBlogRepository>().To<BlogRepository>();
        _kernel.Bind<ILanguageRepository>().To<LanguageRepository>();
        _kernel.Bind<IFrUserRepository>().To<FrUserRepository>();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the exception ?

Comment: I update my question add my the exception detail.Sorry for the exception detail language :(